# Knowledge in French for job or postdoc in France

Tags: recruitment, france

I am looking for postdoctoral position and job related to chemistry in France. I am not a French citizen, but have qualified DELF B1 in French. I have been told that DELF B2 qualification helps in getting job / postdoc in France.

I wanted to know, how much the knowledge in French helps in landing a job in France